# Why did Mordecai behave towards Haman in this way?

Tags: tanach, megillat-esther

Haman was enraged at Mordechai's behavior, according to Megilat Esther he investigated his people and directed his hatred and revenge towards Mordecai to all of Mordecai's people, that is, to the Jews. It turns out that the spark for Haman's behavior and the desire to harm the jews began with Mordechai's behavior. Is it permissible to behave as Mordechai did towards Haman and thereby endanger the Jews?

Comment: Mordechai's behavior was not worshipping idols. There is never a reason to worship idols.

Answer (score 1):

The back story behind the relationship between Mordechai and Haman is found in Sefer Yosifun by Yosef ben Gurion.

On the face of it, Mordechai's slight seems insignificant. And in truth, Mordechai did not honor Haman because of the idol hanging from Haman's neck.

But Yosef ben Gurion explains that Modechai specifically, who was a prominent descendant of the tribe of Benyamin was especially hated by Haman, who was a descendant from Amalek.

That when Saul HaMelech sent his soldiers to attack the Amalekites in Gaza, the specific leadership of the mission was given to the soldiers from the tribe of Benyamin.

That these soldiers didn't simply defeat the Amalekite soldiers, the men, they killed everyone they came across, including women and children. That this was in keeping with the same type of treatment that happened with Moshe and Yehoshua.

In the eyes of Haman, Mordechai, a descendant of the tribe that massacred his people deserved a special level of hatred.

Comment: And not to mention that Haman was Mordechai's slave beacuse he couldn't watch over his budget correctly, and needed Mordechai ....